# $_SESSION test at beginning of page is unpredictable - PHP

Tags: php, html, session

At the beginning of an admin page for our site, we test if the $_SESSION variable admin is set, and if it's not, we redirect the user back to the main page with this code:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
{
 echo "<script>window.location='domain';</script>"; //domain is redacted
die();
}
```

Admin accounts have been experiencing a redirect, especially after a login. So, I created a file that echoed a var_dump of the session and investigated, only to find that the admin variable is in fact set and thus the error should not be occurring. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this deviency, particularly directly following the login and the session variables being set? Note: I have already checked if anything is sent out to HTML on the $_SESSION setting page, and like I said, the variables are set.

EDIT: This is at the very beginning of the code

Comment: is there not a logout page where the session gets destroyed?

Comment: Yes, there is, but it is only accessed if someone clicks logout on their page. I just tried it again for another test and this time it worked fine- the inconsistency is bothering as I cannot always reproduce the problem. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need to be able to reproduce the issue in order to help you.

Comment: Hi @ViníciusFagundes, thanks for the link. Unfortunately I can't even reproduce the problem evenly, so I assumed that someone else must have encountered such a particular problem, and might have a solution. I will certainly keep these guidelines in mind if and when I ask something else.

Comment: Session variables time out after a while. But if `var_dump($_SESSION)` shows the variable, then `isset()` should work.

Comment: Hello @A.Johnston, clearly this code you showed is not causing this error itself. Something else is happening. And if we can't reproduce hardly we can help.

Comment: If it happens just after login. Check and show us how you are setting `$_SESSION['admin']`. Webserver restarts also can clear sessions.

Comment: Hello everyone, while I was unable to reproduce the problem or find what was causing it, I modified the login page by unsetting any previous sessions that could have lingered before creating any new variables. This has helped tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be happening exclusively after logging in. For anyone else who has a similar issue, be sure to use `session_unset();` to remove any leftover information from previous browsing sessions. Thank everyone else for your help.